# Drupal 8 block and type class

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I wanted to add for block it custom type class in twig layout file: block.html.twig
But i have no idea how to get type. 
Class is just needed for styling needs, cause i have many blocks in multiple languages. I don't want to style elements by their custom ids.

Answer (score 1):

Actually i found one working solution, which one uses Theme hook:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for block.html.twig.
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_block(&$variables) {

  // adding custom attribute class for block
  if ($variables['elements']['#base_plugin_id'] == 'block_content') {
    $blockType = strtr($variables['content']['#block_content']->bundle(), '_', '-');
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'block--type-' . $blockType;
  }
}
```

This one is adding class for custom block types only. But works for my needs.